# Using Datadog's Python API, is it possible to get your own credentials, and if so, how?

Tags: python, authentication, devops, datadog

I am trying to create a function that only works if an admin user runs it and returns an exception otherwise. However, I'm not entirely sure how to go about getting your own credentials. That is, I simply want to check the current user's `access_role`.

To get other people's `access_role`, I could simple run `api.User.get_all()`, which returns something like this:

```
{'handle': 'someone@somesite.com', 'name': None, 'access_role': 'st', 'verified': False, 'disabled': False, 'is_admin': False, 'role': None, 'email': 'Someone@SomeSite.com', 'icon': 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/000000000000000000000000000000000?s=00&z=retro'}
```

The `access_role` field displays one of 3 options:

- `adm` ~ admin user
- `st` ~ standard user
- `ro` ~ read-only user

What I've been trying to do is to create a `get_me()` function that takes **no parameters** and returns all this information, but for whoever is calling it.

As far as the `get_me()` function goes, I'm having a touch time finding resources online.

```
# Function that returns the current users information
def get_me():
    # If there is a command to do this, I'd put it here...
    return api.User.some_command();
```

Hopefully though, I can apply the end result to a function like `delete()` as such:

```
# Deletes a dashboard iff the user is an admin user
def delete(self, idno):
    cred = self.get_me();
    if cred['access_role'] == 'adm':
        print 'Dashboard successfully deleted!'
        return api.Dashboard.delete(idno);
    else:
        print 'Not authorized to delete this Dashboard!'
        return api.Dashboard.get(idno);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the code have access to the email of the user? If yes, then you should be able to use the [single "get user" api](https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/?lang=python#get-user) and feed the email into it. The response you would get includes lots of interesting stuff for this use-case, like so:

```
'access_role': 'st',  # etc
'disabled': False,
'role': None,
'is_admin': False,
```

Also, dashboards do have a "permissions" setting with which you can set the dashboards to be "read-only" for anyone who is not the dashboard creator / an admin. That should be set-able via the api too.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the post. I would assume so, because it knows exactly what user posted a new object when used. But, it doesn't seem to have a way to allow that user to essentially check what their own credentials actually are. The User API is what I am currently using. Ideally, I was trying to do something like `api.User.get(self.id)` or something like that.

Comment: oooh, i don't think that's how `api.User` works within the datadogpy library. That "User" class doesn't actually have anything to do with the user of your script per se. But you _could_ probably write your own User class that takes the handle of the script's user as an argument and feeds it into `api.User.get()` in it's own initialization. But the API call on `api.User.get()` does need to know which user to call info for, and the Datadogpy library has no way of getting that on its own, i'm pretty sure.

Comment: food for thought: the Datadogpy library does have a .dogrc file setup to reference user-specific api/application keys. The same could presumably be done for user handle for your own user management work. [Reference](https://help.datadoghq.com/hc/en-us/articles/211364766-Dogshell-Quickly-Use-Datadog-s-API-from-Terminal-Shell)

Answer (score 0):

The API only verifies through API/ App keys, which are pretty much admin users. There isn't any way to add user-level authentication to the endpoints.

You would need to have some kind of authentication on your end that proves who a user is, then compare that with the admin list on DD, then, if they are legit, call your API script. Maybe skip all that have a machine that only DD admin users can access and run the API script from there.